# Rails 3.2 Assets in Production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I'm at my wits end with this. It seems all of the newer rails apps I make its set a couple of configs in `environments/production.rb`, deploy and move on with my life. But now we're migrating a few rails apps to a new server and it seems all of them have this issue when deploying to production.

What appears to be happening is that neither my javascripts or stylesheets are getting compiled. And I see none of the styles for the app and the javascript does not work.

**config/application.rb:**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ... omitted code ...
    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'


    config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :scss
  end
end
```

**config/environments/production.rb:**

```
MyApp::Application.configure do

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  ... omitted code ...
end
```

**In my application-<...>.js:**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from     http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree
;
```

And my application-<...>.css is completely empty.  What am I missing?

Comment: what's the problem? Im assuming styling is not being reflected from dev to production server?

Comment: Hey do you have a javascript env set up on your new server to be able to compile your assets? (nodejs for example). If not add therubyracer into your Gemfile and do a test.

Comment: Yes both CSS and javascript are not working in production. I'm using 'therubyracer' gem for assets

    `gem 'execjs', gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby gem 'libv8', '3.3.10.4'`

Answer (score 0):

So after a long half day yesterday and about an hour today, I suddenly realized something... I ran into this before.

Sure enough... Updating rails to 3.2.14 and deploying again fixed the whole thing.